# Tools for finding domain names

Tags: domain, domain-registrar, whois, domain-registration

I've built out a pet project of mine, and am now looking for a good domain name for it. Arbitrarily doing whois lookups on ideas that pop into my head seems inefficient.

What tools do you use when searching for a good domain name?

Some ideas to get the wheels greased :

- given a few letters does prefix/suffix/infix searches for available domains
- suggests other words from a thesaurus
- shows you short available domains

And of course, another requirement is that the tool isn't shady and quickly registers the domain name while it searches for you.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote because it's not a bad question, but c'mon - you're after a cybersquatting tool, which opens quite a few legal issues these days. In Australia cybersquatting is quite illegal, don't know about other countries.

Comment: I tend to agree with you Farseeker but we do need to remember that while it's illegal here in Oz it's not illegal in some other places. Besides, we're sysadmins, not lawyers.

Comment: Very true. I believe I've seen the acronym SFANL or something, Server Fault Are Not Lawyers...

Comment: Honestly, I don't want to cybersquat. I hate those people just as much as you do. I just want a good name for my pet project. Some searching turned up http://www.nameboy.com/ which isn't too bad. I'm just looking for similar things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May not be a complete solution -- but, try [**Domize.com**](https://domize.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy playing around with [AjaxWhois](http://ajaxwhois.com). It doesn't fit your search criteria at all, and I don't know about the shadiness, but it's damned fun to use!

Comment: this is not bad.  but domize is similar and does it better.  fyi. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of avoiding auto-parking of your queries, I recommend that you do a simple nslookup of www.name.tld and *then* go to your respected registrar when you're ready to purchase it and verify that it is free.

Can't help much in the way of tools, though.  I usually look them up by hand, and if I'm looking for a prefix or substring, I'll whip up a little shell script to search the name space for me.

Answer (score 1):

Most registrar sites I've seen have that kind of functionality. Enter a name you're interested in and they pop up a whole bunch of alternatives. If you need more than that I'm inclined to agree with Farseeker's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Another good site for finding domain names is http://www.bustaname.com  They allow you to combine pre- and post- fixes, creating word lists, and only show results that are still open.

Answer (score 1):

I just script nslookups, then when I have a list of possibles I throw them into a registrar's form, like [gandi.net](http://gandi.net).

Comment: You can submit up to 50 domains in one go on gandi.net

Comment: Yeah having a real variety of options in one click is great. Fifty should be enough for candidate names for a project/product.

Answer (score 0):

I found mine after looking up synonyms for words associated with my project on http://thesaurus.reference.com/ and checking the domains on my registrar.